# Can't delete an unsigned char* after inserting data

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code

```
unsigned char _binary[] = {'1','1','1','0','0','0','1','0',NULL};
int length = 0;
for(length=0;_binary[length];length++);
unsigned char *_hexaActual = new unsigned char;
ConvertBinaryToHexaDecimal(_binary, length, _hexaActual);   
string _actual((char*)_hexaActual); 
delete[] _hexaActual; // crashes here
```

Now the `ConvertBinaryToHexaDecimal` is

```
void ConvertBinaryToHexaDecimal(const unsigned char* _inputBinary, unsigned int _intputLength, unsigned char* _outputHexaDecimal)
{       
    const unsigned char _hexaDecimalSymbols[16] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7',
        '8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

    char* _binary =(char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    int _binaryIndex,_inputIndex;
    for(_binaryIndex=0; _binaryIndex < _intputLength%4 ;_binaryIndex++) // padding extra 0's to make the length multiple of 4
        _binary[_binaryIndex] = '0';
    for(_inputIndex=0; _inputIndex < _intputLength ;_inputIndex++)
        _binary[_inputIndex + _binaryIndex] = _inputBinary[_inputIndex];
    _binary[_inputIndex + _binaryIndex] = NULL; 

    _intputLength = _inputIndex + _binaryIndex;
    for( _inputIndex=0; _inputIndex < _intputLength; _inputIndex +=4)
    {
        int _binaryValue = _binary[_inputIndex] - 48;
        int _binaryValue1 = _binary[_inputIndex+1] - 48;
        int _binaryValue2 = _binary[_inputIndex+2] - 48;
        int _binaryValue3 = _binary[_inputIndex+3] - 48;

        int _hexValue = _binaryValue3 * 1;
        _hexValue += _binaryValue2 * 2;
        _hexValue += _binaryValue1 * 4;
        _hexValue += _binaryValue * 8;

        _outputHexaDecimal[_inputIndex/4] = _hexaDecimalSymbols[_hexValue];
    }
    _outputHexaDecimal[_inputIndex/4] = NULL;
}
```

It outputs corretly a hexa decimal value. But when I try to delete it the program crashes.

EDIT: The crash message says HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED.

Comment: You allocated one char, not array. Use 'delete _hexaActual;'

Comment: I have tried that. Also crashes.

Comment: You allocated one char. You need more than one. Consider using `std::string` rather than juggling pointers and hoping for the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocated a single `unsigned char` with `new`, so you should call `delete`, not `delete []`. The latter is for arrays allocated with `new []`.

You need

```
delete _hexaActual;
```

Note that this type of manual allocations and de-allocations are error prone and exception unsafe. It is likely that you can implement your code using standard library containers and algorithms.

**Edit**: besides that error, you have a few more: The most important one, in the function `ConvertBinaryToHexaDecimal`, you are passing a pointer to a single `unsigned char`, but you are treating it like an array:

```
_outputHexaDecimal[_inputIndex/4] = ....
```

Next, you hve a memory leak. You allocate here:

```
char* _binary =(char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

and never call `free`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to  mention that I have tried what you mentioned. But it still crashes. The for statement is in a function. `_hexaActual` is received as an unsigned char pointer in that function.

Comment: @Tahlil You still have the same problem, and many others. Your code is a bag of bugs.

Comment: I can't find any bug. I am still learning c/c++. Can you please point them out? Thanks.

Comment: @Tahlil I pointed out a couple. But note that this is very un-idiomatic C++. It is very easy to write bugs with code like this. You should try to void all these raw pointers to dynamically allocated data. Or, if you have to code like that, learn to use a debugger, because you will need it :-)

Comment: I thought character pointers are used as arrays. Can you please explain what is wrong with them being used as array? Thanks.

Comment: Also I don't understand why it will crash?

Comment: @Tahlil No, an array is an array. A single `char` is not an array. Unfortunately, a pointer can point to the first element of an array (in which case it can be used as an array, if you know its size), or to a single object. You are making your pointer point to a single object, and using it as if it pointed to an array.

Comment: It also crashes when I call free on `_binary`. Maybe its the same problem as `_hexaActual`, being used as array. I understand this is not good practice. I will avoid it. But I don't understand the exact reason for its crash. To my thinking I am deleting a single character pointer.

Comment: @Tahlil Any one of the errors mentioned so far can result in a crash. So you have to fix *all* of them. I am sure there are other errors lurking around but better fix the obvious ones first.

Answer (score 0):

You only allocated one char for `_hexaActual`, but you are writing many values to it inside `ConvertBinaryToHexaDecimal`. You need allocate enough space for the characters you are going to put in there. `length/4 + 2` should do it.

```
unsigned char *_hexaActual = new unsigned char[length/4 + 2];
```

Comment: But why it will crash if I use it an array and then delete it? Its still a single pointer which was allocated a memory right?